# CentOS6 - Starting OpenVPN: Failed

Tags: centos, openvpn

Let me preface this by saying I'm pretty clueless with it comes to VPNs, so if you need any further info just ask - I'm not purposely being vague I just have no clue.

So I want to install OpenVPN onto a CentOS6 server.  I've followed this guide:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-6

All the certificates have successfully generated, however when I come to start OpenVPN, I get the following:

```
service openvpn start
Starting openvpn: [FAILED]
```

Where should I be looking to remedy this? I've hit a brick wall.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious, but sometimes overlooked thing, make sure you are running service commands as an account with root privileges. Additionally, you could try checking /var/log/openvpn.log:

```
tail /var/log/openvpn.log
```